# how to load an RDBMS driver for h2o in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, rdbms, h2o

I'd like to create a self-contained Jupyter notebook that uses h2o to import and model data that resides in a relational database. [The docs](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/3867/docs-website/h2o-docs/getting-data-into-h2o.html#jdbc-databases) show an example where h2o is launched with the JDBC driver in the classpath, e.g.

```
java -cp <path_to_h2o_jar>:<path_to_jdbc_driver_jar> water.H2OApp
```

I'd prefer to start h2o from a notebook that's a standalone, reproducible artifact rather than have special steps to prep the environment prior to running the notebook. If I run the following snippet:

```
import h2o
h2o.init()

connection_url = "jdbc:mysql://mysql.woolford.io/mydb"
select_query = "SELECT description, price FROM mytable"
username = "myuser"
password = "b@dp@ss"
mytable_data = h2o.import_sql_select(connection_url, select_query, username, password)
```

... the `import_sql_select` method fails because the driver isn't loaded:

```
Server error java.lang.RuntimeException:
  Error: SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://mysql.woolford.io/mydb
```

Is there a way to load the driver when the `h2o.init()` call is made? Or a best practice for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`h2o.init()` takes a parameter called `extra_classpath`. You can use this parameter to provide the path to the JDBC driver and H2O will launch with the driver.

This option is designed exactly for the purpose of not having to start H2O outside of the notebook interface.

Example:

```
import h2o
h2o.init(extra_classpath=["/Users/michal/Downloads/apache-hive-2.2.0-bin/jdbc/hive-jdbc-2.2.0-standalone.jar"])
```

Comment: Thanks, @Michal. That's perfect. I should have figured that out myself via `help(h2o.init)`. Duh.